# Can't delete Node from a BST - C#

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am learning data structures, lately I've been trying to create a BST. Here is the code for that:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BST tree = new BST();
        tree.Insert(3);
        tree.Insert(6);
        tree.Insert(12);
        tree.Insert(2);
        tree.Insert(8);

        tree.InOrder(tree.root);
        // output: 2 3 6 8 12

        tree.Delete(12);

        tree.InOrder(tree.root);
        // output: 2 3 6   
    }
}

class Node 
{
    public Node lc;
    public int value;
    public Node rc;
}

class BST 
{
    public Node root;

    public BST() 
    {
        root = null;
    }

    public void Insert(int value) 
    {
        Node temp = new Node();
        temp.value = value;

        if (root == null)
        {
            root = temp;
        }
        else 
        {
            Node parent = null;
            Node current = root;

            while (current != null) 
            {
                parent = current;

                if (value <= current.value)
                {
                    current = current.lc;
                }
                else 
                {
                    current = current.rc;
                }
            }

            if (value <= parent.value)
            {
                parent.lc = temp;
            }
            else 
            {
                parent.rc = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Delete(int value) 
    {
        Node current = root;
        Node parent = null;

        while (current != null) 
        {
            parent = current;

            if (value <= current.value)
            {
                current = current.lc;

                if (current.value == value) 
                {
                    parent.lc = null;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                current = current.rc;

                if (value == current.value)
                {
                    parent.rc = null;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void InOrder(Node root) 
    {
        if (root != null) 
        {
            InOrder(root.lc);
            Console.WriteLine(root.value);
            InOrder(root.rc);
        }   
    }
}
```

However, I am encountering an issue with deleting the Node identified, as of now I am writing the code for deleting a node which doesn't have any children.

For some reason when I try to delete the Node with which holds the value 12, the Node with the value 8 gets deleted too....I tried to dry run, but still can't understand why I am loosing connection with that other Node which holds 8.

Comment: 8 is the left child of 12, when you delete 12 you lose 8 as well.
You need to handle deletion not assuming you delete leaf nodes only

Comment: It's not the left of 12 but 6, here's the pic of my tree. https://ibb.co/jv7Pvz

Comment: I am sorry, I made a stupid mistake, I was drawing the tree incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

All right, so it turned out as Sasha pointed, I was drawing the tree incorrectly and was loosing the connection to the Node that holds the value of 8 because it was connected to the left of the Node that was deleted.